# NodeJs Can't catch error

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I use the module [omdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/omdb) and I have some trouble catching errors when using it. The error is caused by one of the two methods below, but the stacktrace does not show which. Furthermore, none of the `console.log`s fires either, so I assume that I've made some mistake trying to handle possible errors. The description for omdb.poster is:

> Returns a readable stream of the poster JPEG.

```
function downloadImage(show, callback) {
    var filename = show.title + + " " + show.year + ".jpg";
    var path = "./images/" + filename;
    omdb.poster(show)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("Download Omdb image err: " + err + " for " + show.title + " " + show.year);
            callback(err, null);
        })
        .on('close', function() {
            callback(null, path);
        });

}

function getOmdbInfo(show, callback) {
    omdb.get(show, true, function(err, movie) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("err:" + show.title + " " + show.year);
            callback(err, null);
        }
        if(!movie) {
            console.log("No OMDB info results for: " + show.title + " " + show.year);
            callback('Movie not found!', null);
        } else {
            callback(null, movie);
        }
    });
}
```

Error:

```
\node_modules\needle\lib\needle.js:81
      throw new TypeError('URL must be a string, not ' + uri);
            ^
TypeError: URL must be a string, not null
    at Object.Needle.request (\node
_modules\omdb\node_modules\needle\lib\needle.js:81:13)
    at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as get] (\node_modules\omdb\node_modules\needle\lib\needle.js:425:19)
    at \node_modules\omdb\index.js:251:26
    at \node_modules\omdb\index.js:198:13
    at done (\node_modules\omdb\node_modules\needle\lib\needle.js:234:9)
    at PassThrough.<anonymous> (\node_modules\needle\lib\needle.js:363:11)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Comment: Could you please specify the `show` variable?

Comment: `var show = {title: title, year: year};` example `{title: "Fargo", year: 2004}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises because I catch the order after trying to pipe the file.
By changing this:

```
omdb.poster(show)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("Download Omdb image err: " + err + " for " + show.title + " " + show.year);
            callback(err, null);
        })
        .on('close', function() {
            callback(null, path);
        });
```

To this:

```
omdb.poster(show)
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("Download OMDB image err: " + err + " for " + show.title + " " + show.year);
            callback(err, null);
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
        .on('close', function() {
            callback(null, path);
        });
```

The error is catched.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this part of the [omdb lib](https://github.com/misterhat/omdb/blob/master/index.js):

```
module.exports.poster = function (show) {
    var out = new stream.PassThrough(),
        req;

    module.exports.get(show, false, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            out.emit('error', err);
        } else if (!res) {
            out.emit('error', new Error('Movie not found'));
        } else {
            req = needle.get(res.poster);

            req.on('error', function (err) {
                out.emit('error', err);
            });

            req.pipe(out);
        }
    });
```

an educated guess is that the internal `module.exports.get` method passes an invalid url to the internal `.get()` method (I assume that `res.poster` does not exist). To be entirely sure - please test only the `getOmdbInfo` for the given movie - my tests returned no movie object for the 'Fargo' example.

Comment: You are right in that res.poster did not exist for the movie I attempted. The Fargo example was made up, the actual movie was made in 1996. But this is not the cause of my problems. I will post a solution

Comment: Caught me there with that fake year. Still, with the correct year your code works (at least on my mashine).

Comment: Yes, it happens with movies that exists on Imdb, but does not have a poster (example: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3741316/)